# Format Carbon::Now issues on Seeder

Tags: php, laravel, date

I'm inserting some test data into my db for a posts table.

I am trying to format the Carbon post created date to read as for example if the post was created on 20-06-2016 it would read 20th June, 2016.

Here is my code

```
'post_created_date' => Carbon::now()->format('d-m-y')
```

How do I format it to display this? Currently everything I try doesn't work and it just defaults to Y-m-d

Thanks so much for any help.

Please don't get the wrong idea if you think Im being lazy, I've read the data mutator docs on the laravel website but I'm struggling to see a solution.

Answer (score 1):

For a data format such as `20th June, 2016.`

```
'post_created_date' => Carbon::now()->format('mS F, Y')
```

Source the php [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format.

Though, I don't recommend you save dates in your database in this format.  It's better to save the date in regular mysql format and do the formatting in the view.